# Почему получаю неверное колличество строк при обращении к субпартиции?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, partition

Выполняю следующие действия. Создаю партиционированную таблицу:

```
create table del_part
(
    id      integer generated as identity, 
    dt1     date not null,
    int1    integer not null
)
partition by range (dt1) interval (interval '1' day) 
subpartition by range (int1)
(
    partition p1 values less than (to_date('01.01.2015','dd.mm.yyyy')) 
    (
        subpartition sp1 values less than (100),
        subpartition sp2 values less than (200),
        subpartition sp3 values less than (300),
        subpartition sp values less than (maxvalue)
    )
)
enable row movement;
```

Заполняю ее данными:

```
insert into del_part(dt1, int1) values (sysdate, 99);
insert into del_part(dt1, int1) values (sysdate, 110);
insert into del_part(dt1, int1) values (sysdate, 281);
insert into del_part(dt1, int1) values (sysdate, 99);

insert into del_part(dt1, int1) values (to_date('22.01.2018','dd.mm.yyyy'), 99);
insert into del_part(dt1, int1) values (to_date('23.01.2018','dd.mm.yyyy'), 125);
insert into del_part(dt1, int1) values (to_date('25.01.2018','dd.mm.yyyy'), 766);
insert into del_part(dt1, int1) values (to_date('27.01.2018','dd.mm.yyyy'), 500);

commit;
```

Пытаюсь выбрать данные из сабпартиции, где значение колонки `int1 = 99`, а колонки `dt1 = '21.01.2019'` (`sysdate` на сегодня).
Ожидаю увидеть 2 строки, а получаю все данные из партиции:

```
select *
from del_part    
subpartition for ( to_date('21.01.2019','dd.mm.yyyy'),99);
```

Видимо я что-то делаю не так. Не подскажете, что именно?

---

Версия: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit

Comment: это дополнительное указание для from, как бы определение из какой таблицы брать данные, если представлять субпартиции как отдельные таблицы. и заданный там ключ служит только для уточнения куда обращаться. он никак не влияет на фильтрацию получаемых данных. фильтрацию надо производить как обычно, в where

Comment: @Mike: То есть получается что обращения partition / subpartition for идентичны по сути и влияют только на производительность выборки на уровне "железа" (размещение сабпартиции в определенном файле)? Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: да. они только для указания физического размещения. дополнительный синтаксис делающий то же вещи, что where смысла вводить нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В действительности ошибка в том, что таблица партиционированна неверно. Субпартиции указаны только для партиции по умолчанию `p1` с ключом `01.01.2015`. То есть, все новые записи попадут в соответствующие партиции с **одной единственной субпартицией** для любого значения ключа субпартиции.

Так что, ожидаемый ТС результат вполне оправдан, и при правильном партиционировании запрос должен вернуть две строки.

Заглянем в документацию [гл. Creating Composite Interval-Range Partitioned Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/create-composite-partition-table.html#GUID-E204E851-9B8F-4283-B7D5-88D93DE09B14):

> To define range subpartitions for future interval-range partitions, **you must use the  subpartition template**.
>
> If you do not use the subpartition template, then **the only subpartition that is created**
> for every interval partition **is a range subpartition with the MAXVALUE upper boundary**.

Сделаем как там сказано:

```sql
create table del_part (
    id      integer generated as identity, 
    dt1     date not null,
    int1    integer not null)
partition by range (dt1) interval (interval '1' day) 
subpartition by range (int1) subpartition template (
    subpartition sp1 values less than (100),
    subpartition sp2 values less than (200),
    subpartition sp3 values less than (300),
    subpartition sp  values less than (maxvalue)) 
(partition p1 values less than (to_date ('01.01.2015','dd.mm.yyyy')))
/
```

Теперь результат соответствует ожидаемому:

```
select *
from del_part subpartition for (to_date ('14.06.2020','dd.mm.yyyy'), 99);

        ID DT1                       INT1
---------- ------------------- ----------
         1 2020-06-14 23:10:58         99
         4 2020-06-14 23:10:58         99
```

**Важно**
Значение 99, это ключ партиционирования, а не как указал ТС: *значение поля int1 = 99*.
То есть, можно указать любое значение меньше 100, например 69, результат не изменится. Будут выбраны **все записи** из указанной субпартиции, в примере их только две.